# making a request to an insecure endpoint(http)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront

I have been having an issue with my rails app not generating https assets. I have set `config.action_controller.asset_host` equal to `https://` version of my cloudfront assets but I still seem to get:

`Mixed Content: The page at URL was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I have set cloudfront to `https only` but it still seems to be generating the http version. I can see where it sets the `fontAwesomePath` but I can't seem to find where it is being included.

I am uncertain as to why it is still being delivered as an http resource and would appreciate any advice

Much Appreciated

chaddpaul

Comment: I see some people are setting up there `config.action_controller.asset_host` like [this](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails/issues/69) but am unsure whether that will fix the issue I am having

Comment: I presume you are actively using FontAwesome in your app. How did you get FontAwesome on the page? ie. via a gem, copy-paste HTML into your application.html.erb layout, etc.

Comment: I am using Amazon S3 and Cloudfront but the specific file that holds FontAwesome is my `bootstrap_and_override.css.less` file. It is being called like this:

@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";`

Comment: The problem will be coming from the `asset-url` function. You'll need to work out how to make that generate either a protocol-less URL (//cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont) or a https URL (https ://cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont). Depending on your Rails version, playing with `config.action_controller.asset_host` may help. `config.force_ssl = true` might also help (assuming you want all your site in https).